# powershell neo4j processing file failed

Tags: database, powershell, neo4j

I am trying to run `neo4j-admin.bat` but it fails to run.

The error is:

`Processing -File 'C:\Program' failed because the file does not have a '.ps1' extension. Specify a valid Windows PowerShell script file name, and then try again.`

---

I have tried doing this:

`Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned`

before running:

`bin\neo4j-admin.bat load --from="C:\Users\Name\Downloads\2019-03-08_2019onosh-fix.dump" --database=2019onosh.db --force`

---

It should be able to load a `.dump` file into the database

Comment: start-process ".\bin\neo4j-admin.bat"

Check this link: https://www.jamsscheduler.com/2012/04/24/how-to-execute-a-bat-file-within-a-powershell-job/